# Generating time series data using cassandra stress test

Tags: cassandra-stress

Is it possible to configure Cassandra stress test tool to generate insert workload for time-series data. More specifically provide a columnspec property on a timestamp column  that will either

1. Increment the inserted value as the test progresses (say x secs for every record)
2. Use the current system time (I'm ok running the test for a day)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to insert epoch time, this way you can give the range for long values in your columnspec as below.

```
columnspec:      
    - name: col1
      population: uniform(1497510499000..1497596899000)
```

will give you the range from 2017-06-15 07:08:19.000000+0000 to 2017-06-16 07:08:19.000000+0000. You can change the distribution as per your requirement.